# Help me understand the usage of "edition" in "Apple Watch Edition"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am not sure how to put this, but shouldn't it be < Apple Watch > < _____ Edition >?

In my understanding, it is usually *product* followed by *edition*, and something to indicate what edition it is. For example, Collector's Edition, Special Edition, Limited Edition, Deluxe Edition.

Using < Apple Watch > < Series 2/3/4 > as example, Apple Watch Edition is like saying Apple Watch Series. What series?

**Edited for context/clarity:**
Apple Watch Edition was announced with the first Apple Watch introduction. You can refer to Apple Watch, Apple Watch Sport, and Apple Watch Edition here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150101174240/https://www.apple.com/watch

This website (https://www.imore.com/apple-watch-edition) has the full list of the original Apple Watch Edition collection, and when Apple added Ceramic into the collection, notice how the same website calls it "Ceramic Edition" (https://www.imore.com/apple-watch-3-edition).

In my understanding it has always been "*something* Edition", so when I first came across Apple Watch Edition, that *something* is missing and I always feel incomplete reading it, thus my original question.

However, having revisited the original archived Apple website now made me realize they were referred as "collection", as in Apple Watch Edition collection. Used with word "collection", it does make more sense to me. You have the Sport collection, as well as the Edition collection.

Comment: Sounds like they're trying to snoot it up prestige wise. Lincoln Town cars have long come in "Editions" and "Special Editions": http://www.curbsideclassic.com/automotive-histories/top-10-obscure-special-editions-and-forgotten-limited-run-models-lincoln-mercury-edition-part-i/ I think Cadillacs do the same. I've heard it makes me feel better about myself when my watch is a special edition.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Sorry, but I think you misunderstand my question. My question is towards the "incompleteness" of the phrase. From your examples, they are "Special Edition", "Mercury Edition", "Cypress Edition", but in the case of Apple Watch, there is no "special, mercury, cypress, limited, deluxe, etc" edition. It's just "Edition". I'm trying to understand how the word "edition" is used here, as I have not seen the word "edition" being used elsewhere by itself.

Comment: @guest Could you add the context in which you're seeing this? I looked at the apple website and saw several versions of their watch, but none called the "Apple Watch Edition" as you seem to be describing. Is it possible you're looking at some kind of accessory which comes in an Apple Watch edition and some other editions which are compatible with other products?

Comment: @guest I did misunderstand. So their putting out several version, but mostly *not* distinguishing by name: https://www.apple.com/watch/compare/ That *is* odd. Plain, Nike and Hermes, plus the older version.

Comment: @ChrisH Apple Watch Edition has been discontinued. It was announced with the first Apple Watch introduction. You can see there are Apple Watch, Apple Watch Sport, and Apple Watch Edition by referring to the archived web page of the Apple website here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150101174240/https://www.apple.com/watch/

Comment: @ChrisH Revisiting the website, I now noticed they are referred as "collection" - Apple Watch Edition collection. Used with word "collection", now it makes more sense to me. You have the Sport collection, as well as the Edition collection (which has several variations as described here https://www.imore.com/apple-watch-edition)